# Autossh with jump server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 hosts:

Local, Jump and Server

I can connect to through jump easily enough using the -J option everything works fine using standard SSH.

However I want to connect using autossh as the Local machine is unmanned and needs to maintain its connection without human interaction.

Originally I was using autossh without a jump but now requirements/networks have changed and a jump is required.

using autossh (of which runs in as a service in a complicated script to monitor many things) what is the cleanest way to add in this jump? a line I can monitor with an "until" or likewise would be best suited but open to any suggestions or alternatives